# Keep IIS Express Running on dotnet cli web project targetting .NetCoreApp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I have a dotnet cli WebApp in Visual Studio using the new xproj extension and project.json.

```
dotnet new --t web --lang c#
```

I got a site working and running on .NetCoreApp just fine.  However I am not able to load the site in IIS without adding middleware to it depending on IIS, which I'd rather not do.

So I am using IIS Express.

For that I have to Run the project to get IIS to run to be able to use the site, while in debug mode.

What I would like to know is how I can get IIS Express to stay running and instead attach to it when I run the project.

I have read all the guides on disabling "Edit and Continue".  That does indeed work on ASP.Net Web Applications, but this is a dotnet core WebApp and is not the same project type.  It does not have a Properties window with options to disable Edit and Continue and disabling Edit and Continue in the IDE's Debug Options has no effect.

IIS closes when I stop running the project.

Any ideas?

Optionally, how might I configure it to run locally in IIS without relying on it, best option I can come up there is to use Conditional Compilation.

Comment: You should check the description again and make a clear distinguish between IIS and IIS Express. Currently you mix the two and the question is hard to understand.

Comment: The whole thing is kind of irrelevant now that I figured out how to use "dotnet run"  which is what I wanted.  My goal was to have my site running without having the debugger attached.  dotnet run and kestrel works just fine for that.

I will delete this question shortly.

Comment: @Ryios please dont delete this question ... instead consider posting your solution as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The whole purpose of my question was to be able to have my site running without using f5 in Visual Studio and without having the debugger attached.

The solution, turns out, is simple.

You can just run it in Kestrel in a console terminal.

Just open a terminal or command prompt to your projects root and type:

```
dotnet run
```

This will run kestrel against your project and tell you what port it's on.  Then you can hit http://localhost:5000 (or w/e the port is) in your browser.

Update:  You can kill your dependency on IIS Express as well in your entire app and make f5 run in Kestrel.

To do this:

1. Right click your project and go to properties
2. Click the debug tab
3. Click New next to the profile drop down
4. Call it Kestrel Dev
5. Change launch type to "Project"
6. Set the application arguments to "dotnet run"
7. Add an environment variable for "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
8. Set the value to "Development"
9. Add an environment variable for "ASPNETCORE_URLS"

   10. Give it a value of "http://localhost:8080" or whatever url/port you want it to run on.

Repeat the above options for "Kestrel Production" but set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Production"

The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is used to process your json Config Transformations.

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

So what if you want appSettings.json for Development (local), Staging, and Production then you would create 3 appSettings.json files

```
appSettings.json 
appSettings.Development.json
appSettings.Staging.json
appSettings.Production.json
```

Then you make the .Staging.Json etc files optional with the option: true config option above.

So in appSettings.json you have everything that's the same on all environments.

Then in appSettings.Development.json you might have things you only want when running locally.

Etc etc

You create a profile for each environment, so that if you run "Kestrel Development" it uses appSettings.Development.Json

If you run "Kestrel Staging" it uses appSettings.Staging.Json.

If you run "Kestrel Production" it uses appSettings.Production.json.

This also affects the way your tagHelper work in your MVC Views, e.g.

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

In that html, if you are running "Kestrel Development" then the html inside the environment tag for development is output.

If you are running Kestrel Production, then the html inside the environment tag for staging,production is output.

Comment: Glad to help, just wish it didn't take me 2 hours to figure it out.  I recommend reading all the dotnet cli command tutorials before beginning a core project.

Now, I just need to get bundleConfig.Json and all the tag helpers working and I'm in business.

Comment: ok ...as this is all brand new tech i guess more questions and self answers incomming then ? :)

Comment: Worth noting I did figure out how to get it to run in IIS, however because you have to publish it to another folder you can't make changes in the IDE and refresh the page, you have to run dotnet publish everytime you want to see a change, and that defeated the purpose.  So dotnet run appears to be the best way.

Comment: Updated my answer, I figured out how to make f5 run kestrel.  Just edit launchSettings.json after all that and make the kestrel profiles above the IIS Express Profile.

Answer (score 3):

If you run without the debugger (Ctrl + F5 or in the menu Debug -> Run Without Debugger), the application continues to run in IIS Express (assuming you use the default settings). You can make changes and refresh the browser without publishing or restarting.

With regular IIS you can point a website / application to the project folder and you never have to publish after each change.

Comment: Pointing IIS to the project folder does not work with .Net Core.  The project folder doesn't contain the runtime for DotNet Core, thus it can't load.  You have to point IIS at the published Dot Net Core folder, which you get by running DotNet Publish, and will end up in your bin\debug folder, Then you can't make live changes to it, you have to republish with dotnet command line.

The IIS express part is valid though.

Comment: Keeping dotnet run in a terminal window solves the problem, you can make live changes to the site and only have to rebuild for compiled code changes.  I also feel doing it the Kestrel way is the best way because it ensures your development flow fits the cross platform Jedi Ways.

Comment: Pointing to the project folder does work if you have the right configuration, which admittedly is not easy. For example, make sure AspNetCoreModule is installed in IIS, make sure the ApplicationPoolIdentity has permissions on the project folder, make sure web.config doesn't contain parameterized entries like %LAUNCHER_PATH%, that needs replaced with .NET. I forgot some of the trouble needed to pull it off.

Comment: You'll be using Kestrel as the server even when running under IIS or IIS Express. IIS is only the host process.